# SimpleInjector multiple instances being generated

Tags: c#, simple-injector

I´m facing a strange behaviour when using simpleInjector.

The following code illustrates my scenario:

```
class A: IA, IB<D>{}
```

Then, i´m registering it, once per interface´s instance, as follows:

```
foreach (var service in typeof(A).GetInterfaces())
{
    container.RegisterSingle(service, typeof(A));
}
```

My goal, is to be able to retrieve the same instance (singleton), of A, using either IA or IB. IB stands for a eventlistener interface.

**Putting a breakpoint on A´s constructor I can see it being called twice** when the container.verify() method is called, meaning that I´m not having a singleton here.

What´s wrong with this scenario? Do I need to threat generics interface in a different fashion?

Comment: `RegisterSingle` ensures that all dependencies on `IA` will be satisfied by a single concrete instance (such as `A`), and that all dependencies on `IB` will be satisfied by a single concrete instance, but those two concrete instances aren't necessarily the same instance.

Comment: In fact, this behavior isn't 'strange'. You are making three separate registrations, so Simple Injector assumes three singletons, not one.

Comment: ok. got it as soon as I read the answer.IMHO the api itself is a bit confusing at this point, because it´s not that usual to think about three singletons living simultaneously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Register multiple interfaces with the same implementation**
>
> To adhere to the Interface Segregation Principle, it is important to
>   keep interfaces narrow. Although in most situations implementations
>   implement a single interface, it can sometimes be beneficial to have
>   multiple interfaces on a single implementation. Here is an example of
>   how to register this:

```
// Impl implements IInterface1, IInterface2 and IInterface3.
var registration =
    Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration<Impl>(container);

container.AddRegistration(typeof(IInterface1), registration);
container.AddRegistration(typeof(IInterface2), registration);
container.AddRegistration(typeof(IInterface3), registration);

var a = container.GetInstance<IInterface1>();
var b = container.GetInstance<IInterface2>();

// Since Impl is a singleton, both requests return the same instance.
Assert.AreEqual(a, b);
```

Reference: [Register multiple interfaces with the same implementation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto.html#register-multiple-interfaces-with-the-same-implementation)